# Android Studio/Mac - Installation did not succeed...failed due to: 'device '...' not found'

Tags: android, installation

The full message:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'device 
'ZY224LJKKB' not found'
```

Has anyone run into this? I'm on Android Studio 3.5.2 and I'm using a Mac. I haven't been able to find much documentation online. I've tried the usual things -- ie, restarting AS, using a different cable, using different phones.

Comment: Maybe your cape is not good. Please turn on usb debug and set on phone USB Transfer file, it's will be work

Answer (score 0):

Enabling developer options:

**Tap seven times on ‘Build’**

How to find:

- Google Pixel: Settings > System > About phone > Build number
- Samsung Galaxy S7 or earlier: Settings > About device > Build number
- Samsung Galaxy S8 and later: Settings > About phone > Software    information > Build number
- LG G6 and later: Settings > About phone > Software info > Build    number
- HTC U11 and later: Settings > About > Software information > More >    Build number
- OnePlus 5T and later: Settings > About phone > Build number

**Enabling USB Debugging:**

- Open ‘Settings’ again
- You will see a new line at the end of the list called a ‘Developer
  options’
- Turn on ‘USB debugging’

Now when you connect the device to your computer - you will see a message to confirm access to the device, please confirm and even choose the option that will no longer ask you by give it permanent access.